# PHP - php parameters change one keep the others

Tags: php

I have the following urls

```
//Colour
<a href="page.php?color=red">Red</a>
<a href="page.php?color=blue">Blue</a>
<a href="page.php?color=green">Green</a>

//Size
<a href="page.php?size=small">Small</a>
<a href="page.php?size=medium">Medium</a>
<a href="page.php?size=large">Large</a>
```

I would like a customer to choose both a colour and a size.

Question 1:
If the customer chooses blue he will select `<a href="page.php?color=blue">Blue</a>`. Now if he chooses size small, how can I add the size parameter to `color=blue`.

Question 2:
Like in the above. If now the customer decides to keep the colour blue, and change the size from small to medium, using PHP how can I change the URL from 
`page.php?color=blue&size=small` to `page.php?color=blue&size=medium` without losing the `color=blue` parameter and without creating a link for each color and size e.g. `page.php?color=blue&size=small`, `page.php?color=blue&size=medium`, `page.php?color=blue&size=large`, `page.php?color=red&size=small`, `page.php?color=red&size=medium`, `page.php?color=red&size=large`

Thank you.

Comment: You should parse the query string, add / overwrite new values and build a new query string.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: What have you tried so far? (You need to update your question with your current code approach.)

Comment: Your design approach is flawed. If colour and size are decisions made by clicking links, then you can't choose both criteria at once. The second choice would not to be made after the first, e.g. first choose colour, then on the next page size.

Comment: @Utkanos I would like to have everything on the same page.

Comment: If you're using links, you can store the choices in a session, and then check both the session and the $_GET variables for the choices. You'll also have to add in an option to delete the search parameters from the session.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `size` and `color` params from query

```
//Colour
<a href="page.php?color=red&size=<?= $_GET['size'] ?>">Red</a>
<a href="page.php?color=blue&size=<?= $_GET['size'] ?>">Blue</a>
<a href="page.php?color=green&size=<?= $_GET['size'] ?>">Green</a>

//Size
<a href="page.php?size=small&color=<?= $_GET['color'] ?>">Small</a>
<a href="page.php?size=medium&color=<?= $_GET['color'] ?>">Medium</a>
<a href="page.php?size=large&color=<?= $_GET['color'] ?>">Large</a>
```